# Android Getting continuously Bluetooth signal strength of paired devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am listing all paired devices,and it well work but now want to get Bluetooth signal strength of paired devices...i know it will get by use rssi but cannot implement get it continuously in my app..
plz me by giving suitable code as my code...my code is here...

```
public class Security extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{   
     private BluetoothAdapter BA;
     private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;

     ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

     //private Object ImageView;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.security, null);

     BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

     /* starting the bluetooth*/
     on(v);
     pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
     //length=4;
     // int j=1;

     for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
        mylist.add(bt.getName());
        length=j;
        j++;

        bt.getBondState();
    }

     return v;
     }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On resume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     /*************************Bluetooth function****************************/   

       public void on(View view){
          if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
             Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
             startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Turned on" 
             ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else{
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Already on",
           //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
       }

       public void Discovery(View view) {
          if(BA.isDiscovering()) {
            BA.cancelDiscovery();   
           }
       }

       public void list(View view){
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Showing Paired Devices",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(int j=0;j<length;j++) {
        if(v.getId()==j)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mylist.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //hand.update(run,1000);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: do you want for paired devices only.? as you are not making discovery of bluetoothdevices.

Comment: yes only active paired devices...

Comment: if you are considering active device then it will be already paired with your device.

Comment: its all ok but i can not get rssi of active paired devices continuously........

Comment: Hi Dhiman, Have you got solution for this. I am facing same problem. Please help me.

Comment: Same do I. I need at least once RSSI or "in range" recived for paired device

Answer (score 2):

You can get the signal from following code.

Code your activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    // Registering Broadcast. this will fire when Bluetoothdevice Found
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
}

private final BroadcastReceiver BroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String mIntentAction = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(mIntentAction)) {
            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            String mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
        }
    }
};
```

This broadcast will execute when your device will be connected to the remote device.
There are several other action on which you can fire this broadcast. have a look at [here(BluetoothDevice)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

Check following link for constant reading of RSSI

[Tutorial to continuously measure the Bluetooth RSSI of a connected Android device (Java)](http://techtitude.blogspot.in/2013/01/tutorial-to-continuously-measure.html)

Output of link :

[image]

Comment: i know this but it retrieve rssi for one time in running application...I want continuously after time slice in running application..

Comment: then you need to call it constantly. mean in TimerTask

Comment: You can not get rssi with `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` broadcast anymore. It was to be `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` which works differently.

Answer (score 1):

Then if you want to do it in continuously, you need to run it in a service or in a thread. So that you can even add time slots or sleep (waits) measuring the RSSI.