# Signal level (RSSI) Bluetooth from Android

Tags: bluetooth, rssi

Tell me how to programmatically read the signal level (RSSI) of the Bluetooth connection for an already connected device from the Android application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219036/android-getting-continuously-bluetooth-signal-strength-of-paired-devices

Comment: Thanks for the link. But there is no answer I need. I only need the signal level for one already connected BT device. The level must be received periodically, for example 10-60 seconds. I need to get the level from android application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a BLE GATT connection, use [`readRemoteRssi()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readRemoteRssi()) on the `BluetoothGatt`.

Comment: Bluetooth 3.0 connection, not BLE.